# Termcolor remove color from string

Tags: python-3.x, termcolor

In this code it makes the string 'hello' red:

```
from termcolor import colored
a = colored('hello', 'red')
print(a)
```

Is there a way to make the variable a turn into a normal string that is not colored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the first and last 4 characters of the string should remove the colour info. E.g:

```
from termcolor import colored
a = colored('hello', 'red')
print(a)
b = a[5:-4]
print(b)
```

Comment: If you string is both red and bold, this won't work as you would then have to strip the first 8 characters of the string - each escape code is 4 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re


def reset_font(x):
    y = re.sub("\\033\[0m", "", x) # remove end
    z = re.sub("\\033\[.{1,2}m", "", y) # remove front
    return z

from termcolor import colored
a = colored('hello', 'red')
print(a)
print(reset_font(a))
```